# cannot use prog module in caporal

Tags: javascript

I have a problem when i use prog module in caporal. i cannot use it because exist error 'cannot find module prog' . I have import with use 'import prog from "caporal"'. This is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const { program } = require("@caporal/core");
import prog from "caporal"; //not work

program

  .command("random", "Generate random alphanumeric")
  .option("--length", "length of string",prog.Int, 32)
  // .option("--letters", "allow letters or not", true)
  .action(({ logger, args, options }) => {
    // logger.info(options.length)
    let leng = options.length;
    logger.info(leng);
  });

program.run();
```

how i call prog module so that i cannot get error 'cannot find module prog'. Now i use latest version caporal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using ES6 import syntax so you need to transpile it first to plain JS because Node doesn't support it. Try using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). [Here](https://hiteshkrsahu.medium.com/using-es6-in-node-js-server-eba548f013b3) is also a quick guide on how to setup it.

Either that or just write `const prog = require('caporal')` instead of `import prog from "caporal"`